# How to make the vaxis ticks increment equally

Tags: google-visualization

Does anyone know a way to make the vaxis scale increment in whole numbers (so I want it to show 1,2,3,4,5,6).. but the maximum should be variable based on the maximum value.. so setting the ticks fixed is not a option.

I use;

```
vAxis: {format:'\u20AC#', title: 'Euros' },
```

[image]

I know why it doesnt show 1 and 4 in the below example.. because if I show decimals it's actually 1,5 and 3,5. I just want a logic count from 1 till X with steps of 1..

Comment: get the max value and set the ticks option manually

Comment: The old google charts had an option to just say 'I want a ticket every X'.. I cannot imagine they left such a vital feature out..